# which file hold code of uploading logo using Umbraco

Tags: .net, umbraco

I'm working with **Umbraco** and i don't know file structure of **Umbraco** , can anyone tell how to customize Uploading logo using **Umbraco**

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Media type item to your homepage node, then when you uploaded the image you can write some code to show that as a logo.
You can also introduce a new node as website settings node and add the logo as a field over there.

However, I prefer to set logo in my CSS files or hardcoded unless you want to change it regularly or if you want to sell it to multiple customers.